# Mean and variance of two normal distributions.

Tags: probability

Assume X and Y are both normally distributed random variables.

- Assume X is distributed with means of Mx and variance of $\Sigma_x$
- Assume Y is distributed with means of My and variance of $\Sigma_y$

Let there by Z a random variable such as: Z = X - Y
Does that make Z a random variable with the means of Mx - My and the variance of  $\Sigma_x - \Sigma_Y$?

If no what are Z's parameters?

Thanks

Comment: If the random variables are **independent**, the variance of the difference is the **sum** of the variances. More generally if $X$ and $Y$ are any independent random variables with variances $\sigma^2$ and $\tau^2$, then $aX+bY$ has variance $a^2\sigma^2+b^2\tau^2$.  (Your expression for the mean of the difference is right. And $X-Y$ has normal distribution if $X$ and $Y$ are independent normal.)

Comment: One way to tell that the variance of the difference isn't equal to the difference of the variances is that the difference of two variances can be negative, while the variance of any random variable is always nonnegative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should look at $-Y$ as Normal with mean $-M_y$, variance $\Sigma_y$ and use the formula for $Var (X+Y)$.

Alternatively, for any random variables

$E(X-Y) = EX - EY$ and $Var(X-Y) = Var (X) + Var (Y) - 2 Cov (X,Y)$.

Your expression for Variance is almost always wrong. The only obvious casee I can see it is correct is when $Y$ is a constant or $Y=-X$.

What is interesting here is whether $Z$ is normally distributed. The answer is

**Yes if (X,Y) is jointly normal**

**Not necessarily if (X,Y) are only known to be marginally normal**

Consider this construction:

take $X$ to be $N(0,1)$ distribution. Take $Y=X$ if $|X|\leq c$, $Y=-X$, if $|X|>c$, where $c>0$.

Convince yourself $Y$ is also distributed as $N(0,1)$!

here $X-Y=0$ if $|X|\leq c$, else it equals to $2X$, which is never not normal.

Answer (score 0):

var(X+Y) = var(X) +var(Y) + 2*cov(X,Y) 
so we have var(X-Y) = var(X) + var(Y) - 2*cov(X,Y) 
If the variables are independent, then cov(X,Y) = 0, see Andre's comment.